# Error while installing Pop OS 20.04 - Thinkpad T495

Tags: system-installation, bootable, pop-os

I'm trying to install pop os 20.04 on my thinkpad so i've download the proper image from https://pop.system76.com/ and created a bootable usb using rufus.

When I go to the boot section and select the bootable usb, i get this error:

```
error: /casper_pop-os_20.04_amd_64_intel_debug_25/vmlinuz.efi has invalid signature
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

Someone can help me please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable Secure Boot in your BIOS before booting Pop OS.

See: [github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/908 - Invalid signature for kernel #908](https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/908)